# can I have an event only when I type the the 10 th charector?

Tags: jquery

```
 $('#reference').keyup(function () {
        if($('#reference').val().length==10){
              callAjax();
         }
  });
```

here when i type  10 th charector on  a text box called 'reference'
it call a function
.Do any one have any improvement or better way to do this?
can I have an event only when i type the the 10 th charector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer would be NO.

You can't call events with conditions. You need to trigger the keyup event each time and test your condition into the event function.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is pretty much the best route...there is no need to select the element again though, just use `this`:

```
 $('#reference').keyup(function () {
    if($(this).val().length==10){
      callAjax();
    }
 });
```

Or if you're sure it's a `<input>` element:

```
 $('#reference').keyup(function () {
    if(this.value.length==10) {
      callAjax();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement that i suggest you is **cache**:

```
var ref=$('#reference');
ref.keyup(function () {
        if(ref.val().length==10){
              callAjax();
         }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> can I have an event only when i type the the 10 th charector?

If you're asking whether you can have multiple events, the answer is yes—or, at least, the effect is yes.

Using @Nick Cravers [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377571/can-i-have-an-event-only-when-i-type-the-the-10-th-charector/4377596#4377596) as base:

```
$('#reference').keyup(function () {
    var len = this.value.length;
    if(len==10) {
        callAjax();
        // You can do other things here, too
    }
    if(len>100) {
        // Doing something else with a different condition
    }
});
```